# Grails Database migration- manual changelog of insert values to specific column in table

Tags: mysql, grails, database-migration

I have to insert value to existing table with a column which called name.

I use  *Db migration.*

I wrote manually the changelog:

```
changeSet(author: "sara (generated)", id: "1436343845028-82") {
    grailsChange {
        change {
            sql.execute("INSERT into language (name) values ('Abkhazian'),('Swahili'),('Zulu')")
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to do dbm-update I got the following error:

> "liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for
>   change set changelog-1.0.groovy::1436343845028-82::sara (generated):
>        Reason: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'version' doesn't have a default value:
>             Caused By: Field 'version' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: If "language" is a Grails domain class, and you haven't disabled optimistic versioning on it, then you need to supply a value (0) for the "version" column.

Comment: @Joshua Moore- actually if I add a new line of the table in the database the value of the version column is updated automatically to 0.

Comment: Can you share with us the definition of the table?